# Error when trying to get Observable.fromPromise for Angularfire login function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to create login functionality with Angular and Firebase where I get the result of logging in as an observable from my Auth service in my login component. Below is the error i am getting.

```
ERROR in src/app/login/login.component.ts:28:6 - error ng6002: appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
```

Here's my login component TS file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  public form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { 
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group( {
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  login() {
    const inputValue = this.form.value;
    console.log(inputValue.email, inputValue.password);

    this.authService.login(inputValue.email, inputValue.password)
    .subscribe(
      success => this.router.navigate(['/user/home']),
      error => alert(error)

    );
  }
```

Here's my auth service ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { from as fromPromise, Observable} from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private afauth: AngularFireAuth) {

   }

   login(email, password): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(
      this.afauth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Just so you are aware, `fromPromise` is not used anymore, you can just use `from`. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3374

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you, by accident, have put LoginComponent in the `imports` array in the `@NgModule` it's declared. Move it to the `declarations` array.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [/*LoginComponent*/], // <= move it from here
  declarations: [LoginCompoennt] // <= to here

  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```